# Meaning of leading slash in `.gitignore` file

Tags: git, gitignore

If I put a pattern in a `.gitignore` file with a leading slash, does the slash refer to the directory in which the `.gitignore` file is located, or does it refer to the root of the whole repository?

(The man pages I have found have hidden this information carefully.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is the [documentation text](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> - A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname. For example, "/*.c" matches "cat-file.c"
>     but not "mozilla-sha1/sha1.c".

These are my guesses:

- If you use an in-repository-`.gitignore`, the directory in which the `.gitignore`
  is located - it is not really useful to make it relative to the repository root.

  A short experiment with same-named files in the repository root and a subdirectory (and a
  `.gitignore` in this same directory) confirms this.
- If you use an `.git/info/exclude` or `core.excludesfile`, I suppose it is relative
  to the repository root.

  Also this is (for info/exclude) confirmed by the same test (both tests on 1.7.3.4).

Schnouki found the right part of the documentation about this (emphasis mine):

> - [...]
> - Patterns read from a `.gitignore` file in the same directory as the path, or in
>     any parent directory, with patterns in the higher level files (up to the toplevel
>     of the work tree) being overridden by those in lower level files down to the
>     directory containing the file. **These patterns match relative to the location of
>     the `.gitignore` file.** A project normally includes such `.gitignore` files in its
>     repository, containing patterns for files generated as part of the project build.
> - [...]

One could say that this fact could have been repeated again at the later part quoted above, for clarity.

Comment: I've read the doco.  The question is, pathname with respect to what?  I hate the bloody git doco.  Your untested guesses would be more valuable if tested.

Comment: From `man gitignore`, "Description" part: "Patterns read from a .gitignore file. [...] These patterns match relative to the location of the .gitignore file".